# How to make margin-right Less gradually when resize window

Tags: jquery, css

i want to responsive margin-right when i resize window on browser

this is my code

**html**

```
<header id="header"><!-- ... --></header>
<aside id="block">
bolck bolck bolck bolck bolck bolck
bolck bolck bolck bolck bolck bolck
</aside>
<main id="content">
content here content here content here content here
content here content here content here content here

</main>
```

**css**

```
#header {
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
#block {
  margin-right: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
  border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
}
#content {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

i want make margin-right on block Less gradually when resize browser

thanks all

Comment: Use percentages instead of pixels?

Comment: i try that put not working

Answer (score -2):

Try using percentage for the margin-right. Play around with it and find the best result.

Example here:

jsfiddle.net/jnh2dxak/1

Comment: it works for me too. The problem I see is with the question maybe its not clear enough

Comment: @Bokdem downvotes are probably because your post is more of a comment rather than an answer, try adding the fiddle in there or something :P

Comment: Might be possible they see it as a comment.. Still, this might be a solution for his question though.

Comment: I'll add the fiddle in there, see what happens haha

Comment: i want make margin-right on block Less gradually when resize browser

Comment: i want make block fixed when i resize window